# Return only the row with positive amount if all other columns are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns several columns, Date, settle, acctNum, name, TCode, Amount.
The problem is that, there are records that are identical except for the Amount, which has the same absolute value on both records except that it is positive in one and negative in the other. I need to return only the row with the positive value for Amount. Would anyone have any suggestion? Please, see the below example. I need only the row with the positive amount 23450.  I can't just filter out negatives because only negative that meet the conditions of the provided example are of interest. SQL Server 15.0.41

**Example:**

| Date | Settle | AcctNum | Name | TCode | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | 23450 |
| Jan 1 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | -23450 |
| Jan 7 | Y | 111111 | Vic | tabcd | 446623 |
| Mar 20 | Y | 999999 | Yas | tvfeh | 7778 |
| Jan 1 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | 987123 |
| Aug 9 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | 678599 |
| Dec 2 | Y | 564432 | Ali | tgghy | -987699 |

**Expected result:**

| Date | Settle | AcctNum | Name | TCode | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | 23450 |
| Jan 7 | Y | 111111 | Vic | tccwe | 446623 |
| Mar 20 | Y | 999999 | Yas | tvfeh | 7778 |
| Jan 1 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | 987123 |
| Aug 9 | Y | 123456 | Mark | tabcd | 678599 |
| Dec 2 | Y | 564432 | Ali | tgghy | -987699 |

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: I'm with zhiguang on this, group it and then do a max on the value

Comment: @jarlh. Thanks. I've added an example.

Comment: *I need only the row with the positive amount 23450* - what's wrong with `where Amount > 0` or `where sign(Amount) = 1`?

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, e.g. all negative, several positive, or 0. Also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: SSMS is just the IDE-like environment. Tagging it is like tagging Visual Studio for your programming language. Tag the data engine (and version) you're using, not the application you're writing SQL in

Comment: @Stu Thanks. That would be perfect if I were to exclude all negatives. I only would like to exclude those negatives that meet the criterion in the provided example.

Comment: There was never a version 15.0.4. CTP 2 of 2019 started at version 15.0.1000.34.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to skip the "duplicate" rows:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists
  (select 1 from tablename t2
   where t2.Date = t1.Date
     and t2.Settle = t1.Settle
     and t2.AcctNum = t1.AcctNum
     and t2.Name = t1.Name
     and t2.TCode = t1.Tcode
     and t2.Amount = -t1.Amount and t1.Amount > 0)
```

Or use `EXCEPT`:

```
select Date, Settle, AcctNum, Name, TCode, Amount
from tablename
except
select Date, Settle, AcctNum, Name, TCode, -Amount
from tablename
where Amount > 0
```

Comment: @stu thanks so much. Looks very elegant. I will try when I am back at my computer.

Comment: @Didier68 thanks so much! I will try when I am back at my computer.

Comment: thanks so much! I will try when I am back at my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like :

```
select * from <tableName> A where A.Amount >= 0 
or not exists(select * from <tableName> B where B.Amount = -A.Amount
    and B.Date = A.Date and B.settle = A.settle and B.acctNum = A.acctNum 
    and B.name = A.name and B.TCode = A.TCode )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a window count, such as:

```
select *
from (
  select *, 
    Iif(Amount > 0, 1, 
      Count(*) over(partition by Settle, AcctNum, Name, TCode, Abs(amount))
    ) Valid
  from t
)t
where Valid = 1;
```